# How to make a node.js Asynchronous API call and use a returned value?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, promise, axios

It seems like has been asked a 1000 times but in reading all of the responses I still cannot seem to figure out how to make this work.

Here is my use case.

1. Make a call to an Auth Endpoint and return an access token
2. do some updates to the options of a 2nd API call
3. make the next api call with the updated options

I know how to make this work with traditional promises or callbacks but in my case step 1 & 2 could be optional so what I want to do is if step 1 & 2 are required call an async function to get the token and update the options. If 1 & 2 are not required then just make the 2nd API call.

I am trying to use axios but no matter what I do the response is either undefined or

Here is my code, can someone please explain the best way to do this, or is it just easier to use traditional promise\callbacks?

```js
  var options = {
      'method': httpVerb ,
      'url': url,
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyArgs)
    };

    
    if(authBody){
      auth = getAuth(authBody)
      options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + auth.access_token;
      console.log(auth)
    }
    
    
 const getAuth = async (options) => {
  try{
    const resp = await axios.post(options.authURL, options )
    if(resp.status === 200){
      return resp.data;
    }else{
      return ""
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> auth = getAuth(authBody)   // wrong
> ```

`getAuth` is an `async` function, and `async` functions always return Promises even if the `return` statements within them return simple values.

If you want to wait for the return value of `getAuth`, you're going to have to do so in a `then` function on the return value, or `await` the result from within a different `async` function. Consequently, if you have an optional asynchronous step, it is safer to make the whole process appear asynchronous to abstract away the cases where you need to wait to refresh the token.